# JQuery swapping classes

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I'm learning JQuery and when writing my own little scripts, ran into a problem. So I have a navigation bar and each time a button is pressed, it should switch its css class from 'btn' to 'activebtn'. For testing purposes, I would just like to be able to click the SAME button, and have it switch back, although this doesn't happen. Does the JQuery just not update the classes? If this is the case, how would I go about forcing JQuery to do so?

```
<div class="btn">Hello</div>
<div class="btn">World</div>

<script>
$( ".btn" ).click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('btn');
    $(this).addClass('activebtn');
});

$( ".activebtn" ).click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('activebtn');
    $(this).addClass('btn');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Read the Direct and delegated events section at http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Since you can add more than one class to any element, it would probably be easier to just `.toggleClass('active')`

Comment: You can watch what jQuery does with classes in your dev tools inspector. The problem here is that `.activebtn` doesn't exist on page load, when jQuery binds its event handlers. You'd need to use `on()` or, better, tymeJV's solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should just able to do:

```
$( ".btn" ).click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('btn activebtn');
});
```